# Labview type conversion to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I am just hoping for somebody out there who might have an answer.
I am posting here eventually after fruitless dealing with Labview and the Device company.

I am currently making an application to control a device, which is provided with Labview compiled DLL. The dll is compiled with missing some necessary Labview functions not included. So I have to call functions directly using Labview Run Time Engine. The Labview website replied me that I have to deal directly with the device company, which has no solution for me.

There is a labview function called FCreate (Labview Manager Function) which is defined as:

```
MgErr FCreate(File* fdp, Path path, int32 permissions, int32 openMode, int32 denyMode, PStr group);
```

If this function creates the file, the resulting file descriptor is stored in the address referred to by fdp.

And the there is another function called FNewRefNum:

```
FNewRefNum(Path path, File fd, LVRefNum* refNumPtr)
```

This function creates a new file refnum for an open file with file descriptor fd.

The refNumPtr is the one that I have to create and pass in to the dll, which doesn't have above functions compiled with.

I need to know exact type conversions in C# for those two labview functions.
Or at least to C++ then I might able to convert them to C#.

The function calls were tested with Labview runtime engine and the engine seems recognizing. The error currently I am having is **"AccessViolationException was unhandled"**

```
ErroMessage: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Thanks in advance for anyone trying to help.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to call the `FCreate` function? Are you trying to implement the `FCreate` function? Where do its parameters come from?

Comment: yes I am trying to call the FCreate function and then FNewRefNum function from C# by using dllimport. Those functions are supported by lvrt.dll the labview runtime engine dll.  However I need to convert the labview type arguments into C# readable and I am asking help from anyone who can do

Comment: OK, so you need to convert the LabView type arguments into C#. But *from what*?

Comment: That's the problem.. if it was c++ may be I could find some header file regarding the argument types then include the header file.. but in c# I am gonna have to find a way around..?  for example creating some structure for Labview File type.. wish someone knew how Labview File type looks like..In case of LVRefNum, I read some threads people saying LVRefNum is Int32 pointer type. Although in my case, it will be a pointer pointing to open file..

Comment: But how do you know what those values *mean*? Where do you get a value to pass in for `refNumPtr`, for example?

Comment: Hi FNewRefNum() generates refNumPtr and FCreate() creates open file and pass the File* fdp, which I will pass to FNewRefNum() as an argument.  The problem is, I can't use any type to begin with in C# for Labview type File*.     Thanks for your questions though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look in `extcode.h` to see the definitions of the various types. I found an instance online [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads147/sourcecode/windows/other/636407/CallLVArray/extcode.h__.htm):

```
typedef int32   MgErr; 

#define LV_PRIVATE(T)   typedef struct T##_t { void *p; } *T 

/** @struct File 
Opaque type used by the file manager. See filemgr.cpp */ 
LV_PRIVATE(File); 

/** @struct Path 
Opaque type used by the path manager. See pathmgr.cpp 
declared here for use in constant table */ 

typedef struct PATHREF PathRef;
typedef PathRef*        Path;

typedef uChar       *PStr, **PStrHandle, *CStr; 

/** MagicCookie 
Opaque type used by the cookie manager. */ 
typedef uInt32 MagicCookie; 

typedef MagicCookie LVRefNum;
```

To summarize, all of your types are either `int` or `IntPtr`:

```
MgErr: int
File: IntPtr
Path: IntPtr
int32: int
PStr: IntPtr
LVRefNum: int
```

Here's how you might declare the functions:

```
int FCreate(IntPtr* fdp, IntPtr path, int permissions,
            int openMode, int denyMode, IntPtr group);
int FNewRefNum(IntPtr path, IntPtr fd, int* refNumPtr);
```

Comment: Thanks Gabe, I will try the suggested type conversion

Comment: For the benefit of other people, I have to leave comment here that above conversion compiles with no error, however Labview runtime engine still sends me no file descriptor back and I get empty fdp when I call FCreate.

Comment: @JP_medevice: Do you still get an access violation? If not, maybe you are calling the function wrong.

Comment: Hi, I don't get any access violation however returned file descriptor with 0. One thing I added was giving the path a string value using marshal: IntPtr path = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(strPath).